# How can we create temporary list for send SMS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile, list

We need to send SMS to a different audience every day.
We have created an import definition with mobile connect, and have used in automation studio with an Import Mobile contact activity.
We have executed twice this automation, with different contacts form two days, and the list 
has collected all the contacts from these two execution.
But we need to have only contacts from each one, in each send.

Is there any way to remove contacts in a list in mobile connect?
Is there any way to overwrite the list?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you need to do a "refresh mobile filtered list" from within Automation Studio.  Long answer (I've done it like so):

1. Import data, and segment in email part of the app.  Within this step, have a column in your DE with something like "sent", defaulting to N on you're freshly imported data.
2. Run an Import Mobile Contacts Activity from Automation Studio
3. Run a Refresh mobile filtered list activity
4. Do Send.
5. Run a query in email part of app to set the SENT column in DE to Y.
6. Run an Import Mobile Contacts Activity from Automation Studio AGAIN
7. Run a Refresh mobile filtered list activity

Steps 6&7 are optional, I just did it to make absolutely sure no one got another text message.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a great answer!! Saved my bacon!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue recently and found this awesome solution from Timothy. I wanted to post an updated solution as with Contact Builder and the updates to Mobile Connect make the solution above slightly off.

1. You will need a Data Extension(DE) with all the fields you need (must be sendable) and a column 'SENT' with the column defaulting to 'N'
2. Create an attribute group in Contact Builder(CB) based off this DE.
3. Create an Import Mobile Contacts Activity in Mobile Connect(MC) to insert the contacts from the DE into MC.
4. Create a Filtered list in MC using the Attribute group and filtering based on the 'Sent' column. Set to auto-refresh prior to each send.
5. Create an Automation Outbound message in MC.  Make sure to include the following AMPscript in it `%%=UpdateData("YOURDATAEXTENSION",1, "Mobile Number", MOBILE_NUMBER, "Sent","Y")=%%` (This will set the Sent field to 'Y' on each person you send to.
6. (OPTIONAL)Create a mobile list refresh activity on the filtered list. This is not needed, but I like having a fail-safe in case the auto refresh in MC fails.
7. Set this all into Automation Studio.  See below for Order:

   a. Import Mobile Contacts Activity

   b. Mobile List Refresh Activity

   c. Automation SMS Send activity

Answer (score 0):

As @Timothy mentioned, filtered list in MobileConnect can be refreshed in Automation Studio. Refer below screenshot.

[image]